# Truffle does not add "networks" to build/contracts/contract.json after migration

Tags: truffle, testrpc

**Problem**

[Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) does not add "networks" to `build/contracts/contract.json` files after migration.

[image]

---

**Versions running**

- Truffle v4.0.1 (core: 4.0.1)
- Solidity v0.4.18 (solc-js)
- EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2)
- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1

---

**What I have tried already**

1. Downgrading Truffle:
   I have tried to downgrade from Truffle version `4.0.4` to version `4.0.0` and then to `4.0.1` to test if it has something to do with Truffle version, but unfortunately I get the same problem.

`truffle.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
   networks: {
     development: {
       host: "localhost",
       port: 8545,
       network_id: "*" // Match any network id
     }
   }
};
```

2. I also tried to run over port 9545 with `$ truffle develop`, but got the same problem.

---

**Error message**

When I run `$ truffle test` I get the following error message:

> Error: TestContract has not been deployed to detected network
>   (network/artifact mismatch)

---

**What does work**

When I run `$ truffle migrate --reset`, my `build/contracts/Migrations.json` file does have the networks specified like:

```
...
"networks": {
    "1516203204392": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0xa10a9e84eb3ef0bf7ebc1b6337c20031b5a80e69"
    }
  },
...
```

Comment: Can you also add your file(s) from /migrations?

Comment: What is in your migrateion folder? Is there `2_deploy_contracts.js` or some other code which is running to migrate your contracts to blockchain?

Comment: @RomanFrolov the 1_initial_migrations.js file, but I found out that I did not deploy my contract in migrations file for some stupid reason. But now I have the following problem.. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36690/error-encountered-bailing-network-state-unknown-review-successful-transaction

Comment: `truffle migrate --reset` helps me. Just note here so anybody else meet problem can use that :D

Comment: I had the same problem but in my case I had forgotten to add the migration files to my root directory, and adding them solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue,

On closer observation, the issue is with `2_deploy_contracts.js`.
When you are running `truffle migrate --reset` Keep an eye on the text `Saving artifacts...` And also take a look at after which contract deployment this appears, and after this is the problem in the migration file.

I had some async/awaits in there and apparently the code executes but writing the artifacts has some time constraints and runs after the third contract deployment therefore only 3 of my contracts had `networks` populated and rest empty.

Hope this helps someone doing such silly mistakes like me.

Comment: `truffle migrate --reset` helps me. Just note here so anybody else meet problem can use that :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was `async`/`await` calls in the migration that I forgot to add `await` on them. Because of that the migration stalled/stuck forever.