# Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc, crowdsale, openzeppelin

**Problem**

I get the following error after running `$ truffle migrate --reset`:

> Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js   Replacing Migrations...
>   ... 0x5b23d046a48e2b1707155f10d3b6e12848b55167198ebcc27288a51463f2a6d6
>   Migrations: 0x4214c32de196e89f3aec37aa7ec58bf10e84347a   Replacing
>   TestCrowdsale...   ...
>   0x1241cadb6818bdb0cd9698b25b6abfae472c34dfa119107691108e24198db326
>   Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
>   transactions manually. Error: VM Exception while processing
>   transaction: revert
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:43303:16)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:331156:36
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:175492:11
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:314196:9
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:315621:13)
>       at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70159:18)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70449:12)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70604:12)
>       at IncomingMessage. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70564:24)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)

**Environment**

- Truffle v4.0.1 (core: 4.0.1)
- Solidity v0.4.18 (solc-js)
- EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2)

**Migrations file**

My 1_initial_migration.js file looks like:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");
var TestCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./TestCrowdsale.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployer.deploy(Migrations);
   deployTestCrowdsale(deployer);
};

function deployTestCrowdsale(deployer) {

   const accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

   const startTime = latestTime();
   const endTime = startTime + duration.days(45);
   const rate = 2500;
   const goal = web3.toWei(250, 'ether');
   const cap = web3.toWei(4000, 'ether');
   const wallet = accounts[0];

   return deployer.deploy(TestCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, wallet);

}

function latestTime() {
  return web3.eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp;
}

const duration = {
   seconds: function (val) { return val; },
   minutes: function (val) { return val * this.seconds(60); },
   hours: function (val) { return val * this.minutes(60); },
   days: function (val) { return val * this.hours(24); },
   weeks: function (val) { return val * this.days(7); },
   years: function (val) { return val * this.days(365); },
};
```

**Crowdsale file**

TestCrowdsale contract uses the [Zeppelin Solidity framework](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity). My TestCrowdsale.sol file looks like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import 'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol';

contract TestCrowdsale is Crowdsale {

   function TestCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet)
      Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
      public
      {
   }

}
```

truffle.js file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
   networks: {
     development: {
       host: "localhost",
       port: 8545,
       network_id: "*" // Match any network id
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: When I remove the inherited Crowdsale contract from Zeppelin Solidity, the error is gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin of the issue is because you're trying to deploy the contract from the file **migrations/1_initial_migration.js** that is supposed to be used only for the deployment of Migration.sol.

To deploy your contracts, you need to create a file in **migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js** that contains the deployment part of `TestCrowsale.sol`

**migrations/1_initial_migration.js**

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");
module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

**migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
var TestCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./TestCrowdsale.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployTestCrowdsale(deployer);
};

function deployTestCrowdsale(deployer) {

   const accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

   const startTime = latestTime();
   const endTime = startTime + duration.days(45);
   const rate = 2500;
   const goal = web3.toWei(250, 'ether');
   const cap = web3.toWei(4000, 'ether');
   const wallet = accounts[0];

   return deployer.deploy(TestCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, wallet);

}

function latestTime() {
  return web3.eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp;
}

const duration = {
   seconds: function (val) { return val; },
   minutes: function (val) { return val * this.seconds(60); },
   hours: function (val) { return val * this.minutes(60); },
   days: function (val) { return val * this.hours(24); },
   weeks: function (val) { return val * this.days(7); },
   years: function (val) { return val * this.days(365); },
};
```

I tried on my side and the deployment go through :

```
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0x46dd08a7e00419adc52c3b9b048f89812dd960463b02125a93eb7e43eb4ca64f
  Migrations: 0x4a5a1448d37aeaaae79deed7e0d3f81ebc52db87
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x573964afa1f79deca003871bd793026f7c932d9c46b8be055184e10790a63147
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying TestCrowdsale...
  ... 0xd251d1b3b92facb64e38ce3e04907197e9b7b9e7fefdf083da1b43c08f1b9bb1
  TestCrowdsale: 0xd817d9295491556f00a45c8092e42c10df271865
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x83a2ba140f54003fc0f146ff2d8b8e2f6d9013122d59d94a39a74d4a9c8df92e
Saving artifacts..
```

I pushed the code here for more details: https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/36690-error-encountered-bailing-network-state-unknown-review-successful-transaction

Comment: Thanks! This works. I placed the code in the 1_initial_migrations.js file to solve another problem, but because of that I ran into this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Check any abstract/interface methods are being implemented correctly. I get this issue, where it compiles but won't deploy, when I fail to implement abstract/interface methods correctly in inheriting contracts.

Edit: Also check all the require statements in the Crowdsale constructor will pass. Maybe try with hardcoding a `startTime` definitely in the future in the deployment script eg 1999999999.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you're using wrong initialization parameters in your Truffle migration file. As an example, let's consider the following simplified contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Lease {

  function Lease(
                address _owner,
                address _tenant,
                uint _startDate,
                uint _fee,
                uint _deposit)
    public {
    require(_owner != _tenant);
    require(_startDate > now);
    require(_fee > 0);
    require(_deposit >= fee * 2);
  }
}
```

In order to deploy it, assume you're using the following migration file:

```
var Lease = artifacts.require("./Lease.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  var owner = '0xf17f52151ebef6c7334fad080c5704d77216b732';
  var tenant = '0xc5fdf4076b8f3a5357c5e395ab970b5b54098fef';
  var startDate = 1522904400;
  var fee = 1000000000000000000;
  var deposit = 2000000000000000000;
  deployer.deploy(Lease, owner, tenant, startDate, fee, deposit);
};
```

When you run `truffle migrate --reset` you get the aforementioned error. Can you tell what's wrong?

In this case, `startDate` is assigned to a unix time in the past, which causes the second `require` statement in the contract constructor to fail.

Unfortunately, Truffle isn't specific enough about this kind of errors yet, so you have to be very careful about them.