# Got error!!Trying to deploy smart-contracts in ropsten infura

Tags: ropsten, infura

When I am trying to migrate smart contracts in ropsten infura network, but got error.

The error is shown below:

```sh
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Replacing Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC
```

**truffle.json**

```js
    module.exports = {    
    ropsten:{
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC,REMOTE_NODE),
      network_id: 3
     }  
    },
```

Please help me to resolve this and help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be a common problem currently on ropsten after they upgraded to geth 1.10, not sure if it’s a bug or change. try it on rinkeby it will works until the tools are updated or fixed

Comment: The problem is related to the chain id, which should be signed with the transaction.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/22339 this is new in the geth 1.10 version, and cause your problem. try somehow to add the chain id to the transaction sign function which is done in the background for you

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/36692/68019), if it doesn't help please provide us with more details of all the steps you took trying to deploy the contract!